# How can I increase a field in a rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, rubygems, rails-postgresql

I'm getting this error:

```
 SQL (31.1ms)  INSERT INTO "read_marks" ("readable_id", "readable_type", "timestamp", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["readable_id", nil], ["readable_type", "PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity"], ["timestamp", Mon, 04 Mar 2013 03:29:52 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 2]]
PG::Error: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(20)
```

Because "readable_type" only holds 20 characters, and I'm passing in "PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity".

This is the same problem as [using gem unread with public_activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535093/using-gem-unread-with-public-activity) (who apparently solved the problem but didn't say how (see his bottom UPDATE))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make a migration and change `readable_type` to a longer type?  Something like this:

```
change_column :read_marks, :readable_type, "varchar(255)"
```

or if you want to go even longer:

```
change_column :read_marks, :readable_type, :text
```

Since you're using PostgreSQL, there's no disadvantage to using an "unlimited" length type, e.g. `:text`.

Comment: I was like, "There's no way it's that easy" and then it was

Answer (score 0):

From the link you added:

```
UPDATE

AH! It was the readable_type field having a limit of only 20 that was truncating my class name. Now it works after I increased the size.
```

On the database, increase the size of the column "readable_type" to a bigger size than 20